# SQLAlchemy: How do I get an object from a relationship by object's PK?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a one-to-many relationship like this:

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = Column(Integer)
    ...
    library_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("libraries.id"))

class Library(Base):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = Column(Integer)
    ...
    books = relationship(Book, backref="library")
```

Now, if I have an ID of a book, is there a way to retrieve it from the `Library.books` relationship, "get me a book with id=10 in this particular library"? Something like:

```
try:
    the_book = some_library.books.by_primary_key(10) 
except SomeException:
    print "The book with id 10 is not found in this particular library"
```

**Workarounds I can think of (but which I'd rather avoid using):**

```
book = session.query(Book).get(10)
if book and book.library_id != library_id:
    raise SomeException("The book with id 10 is not found in this particular library")
```

or

```
book = session.query(Book).filter(Book.id==10).filter(Book.library_id=library.id).one()
```

Reason: imagine there are several different relationships (`scifi_books`, `books_on_loan` etc.) which specify different primaryjoin conditions - manually querying would require writing individual queries for all of them, while SQLAlchemy *already knows* how to retrieve items for that relationship. Also, I'd prefer to load the books all at once (by accessing library.books) than issuing individual queries.

Another option, which works but is inefficient and inelegant is:

```
for b in library.books:
    if b.id == book_id:
        return b
```

What I'm currently using is:

```
library_books = {b.id:b for b in library.books}
for data in list_of_dicts_containing_book_id:
    if data['id'] in library_books:
        library_books[data['id']].do_something(data)
    else:
        print "Book %s is not in the library" % data['id']
```

I just hope there's a nicer built-in way of quickly retrieving items from a relationship by their id

**UPD:** I've asked the question in the [sqlalchemy mail list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/mwrXAvfRzxg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's query object has `with_parent` method which does exactly that:

> **with_parent(instance, property=None)**
>
> Add filtering criterion that relates the given instance to a child object or collection, using its attribute state as well as an established relationship() configuration.

so in my example the code would look like

```
q = session.query(Book)
q = q.with_parent(my_library, "scifi_books")
q = q.filter(Book.id==10).one()
```

This will issue a separate query though, even if the `my_library.scifi_books` relation is already loaded. There seems to be no "built-in" way to retrieve an item from an already-loaded relation by its PK, so the easiest is to just convert the relation to a dict and use that to look up items:

```
book_lookup = {b.id: b for b in my_library.scifi_books}
book = books_lookup[10]
```

Answer (score 3):

See SQLAlchemy docs on [querying with joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins). So you want something like this (be aware that this is untested):

```
query(Book, Library). \
    filter(Book.id==10). \
    filter(Book.library.id==needed_library_id).all()
```

If `Book -> Library` reference would be scalar, you could use `has()`:

```
query.filter(Library.books.has(id=10))
```

To make batch queries for multiple books at once, you can use `in_()` operator:

```
query(Library).join('books', Book).filter(Book.id.in_([1, 2, 10])).all()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I think your first example does not require a join: `query(Book).filter(Book.id==10).filter(Book.library_id==needed_library_id).one()` - I edited my question to specify why I'd like to avoid this approach.

Comment: After some thinking I see that using a join as in your example would allow to address custom join conditions, as in `Library.books_on_load`, `Library.scifi_books` - very nice. Still, I'd like to be able to load all objects at once instead of issuing a separate query for each one.

Comment: @Sergey To get all objects you probably need to configure eager loading.

Comment: That's the whole point - using session.query() will issue separate SQL queries for each "book" regardless of whether the relationship is already loaded. Eager loading just loads all library's books when the library itself is loaded, it doesn't change the behavior of independent calls to session.query().

Comment: @Sergey Ah indeed, I've been answering it wrongly all the time :S